# implement XGboost custom objective function

Tags: python, r, xgboost

I am trying to implement a custom objective function using XGboost (in R but I also use python so any feedback about python is also good).

I created a function that spit back gradient and hessian (it works properly), but when I try to run xgb.train then it is not working. I then decided to print for each round the predictions, gradient and hessian in this specific order. This is the output (it keeps repeating as long as I let it run):

> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> [1] -0.034106908 -0.017049339 -0.034106908 -0.034106908 -0.034106908
>   -0.034106908 -0.034106908 -0.004256162 -0.034106908 -0.008520554
>
> [1] 0.003836107 0.004272548 0.003836107 0.003836107 0.003836107
>   0.003836107 0.003836107 0.004408935 0.003836107 0.004381658
>
> [0]   train-score:0   val-score:0
>
> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> [1] -0.034106908 -0.017049339 -0.034106908 -0.034106908 -0.034106908
>   -0.034106908 -0.034106908 -0.004256162 -0.034106908 -0.008520554
>
> [1] 0.003836107 0.004272548 0.003836107 0.003836107 0.003836107
>   0.003836107 0.003836107 0.004408935 0.003836107 0.004381658
>
> [1]   train-score:0   val-score:0

We can see that even if gradient and hessian seems ok, the predictions at each round does not change !! 
I don't understand why is that the case.
If anybody ran into the same problem or have an idea please share.

The code I use is the following but I don't think it is very helpful:

```
reg <- xgb.train(data        = xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(train[1:10,feature.names]),label=train$Response[1:10]),
             nrounds     = 1000,
             obj = custom_obj,
             feval = evalerror,
             early.stop.round = 20,
             maximize = TRUE,
             watchlist = list(train = xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(train[1:10,feature.names]),label=train$Response[1:10]),
                               val = xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(cv[,feature.names]),label=cv$Response)),
             param = list(eta         = 0.5,
                          max_depth   = 10,
                          colsample_bytree=0.7,
                          min_child_weight=50,
                          subsample=0.7,
                          base_score = 4))
```

Comment: Why do you use 1:10 in train?

Comment: Just to train it on 10 points, so that I can look at the gradient and hessian easily

Comment: can you update the post with the `custom_obj` implementation?