# Python, XGBoost, custom objective function: predictions remain unchanged over iterations, even with non-zero gradient

Tags: xgboost, loss-function

I am trying to get a custom loss function work with xgboost. I am presenting the results for four choices for objective:

- 'reg:linear'     *defined by xgboost, uses mse*
- mse_approx_obj   *custom using mse, find code below*
- mae_approx_obj   *custom using mean_absolute_error, find code below*
- pseudohuber_approx_obj [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss)

As you can see from the results below, for xgboost defined mse and custom defined mse, the algorithm functions well. However for custom defined mae and smoothed first-order loss function (Huber) the algorithm behaves erratically. For eg., for mae and Huber even when the gradient has a large value, the predictions don't change at all. This seems strange to me. Any pointers?

```
def mse_approx_obj(dtrain, preds):
    d = preds - dtrain   
    grad_mse = d
    hess_mse = np.full(d.shape,1.0)

    return grad_mse, hess_mse

def mae_approx_obj(dtrain, preds):
    d = preds - dtrain
    grad_mae = np.array(d)
    grad_mae[grad_mae > 0] = 1.
    grad_mae[grad_mae <= 0] = -1.
    hess_mae = np.full(d.shape, 0.0)

    return grad_mae, hess_mae

def pseudohuber_approx_obj(dtrain,preds):
    d = preds- dtrain
    h = 1  #h is the delta
    scale = 1 + (d / h) ** 2
    scale_sqrt = np.sqrt(scale)
    grad = d / scale_sqrt
    hess = 1 / scale / scale_sqrt

    return grad, hess

 def model(init_params, training_data, validation_data):

     xgb1 = XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.1,n_estimators=5, max_depth=8, min_child_weight=1, gamma=0, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=0.8, objective = mae_approx_obj, seed=2)

     x_train, y_train = training_data[Xfeatures], training_data[target]
     x_test, y_test = validation_data[Xfeatures], validation_data[target]

     xgb1.fit(x_train,y_train, eval_set=[(x_train,y_train), (x_test,y_test)], eval_metric='rmse', verbose=True)

     return xgb1

xgb1 = model(init_params, training_data, validation_data)
```

The results for the four objectives, respectively:

```
[0] validation_0-rmse:61.5518   validation_1-rmse:57.0926
[1] validation_0-rmse:55.4669   validation_1-rmse:51.2765
[2] validation_0-rmse:49.9936   validation_1-rmse:46.3276
[3] validation_0-rmse:45.0812   validation_1-rmse:41.9738
[4] validation_0-rmse:40.6609   validation_1-rmse:37.9743`

[0] validation_0-rmse:61.5506   validation_1-rmse:57.0223
[1] validation_0-rmse:55.4673   validation_1-rmse:51.5381
[2] validation_0-rmse:49.9943   validation_1-rmse:46.6359
[3] validation_0-rmse:45.0801   validation_1-rmse:42.2759
[4] validation_0-rmse:40.6617   validation_1-rmse:38.3059
```

For mae_approx_obj, I print preds, grad_mae everytime mae_approx_obj is called to help debug the process.

```
[ 0.5  0.5  0.5 ...,  0.5  0.5  0.5]
[-1. -1. -1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]
[0] validation_0-rmse:68.3176   validation_1-rmse:63.0391
[ 0.5  0.5  0.5 ...,  0.5  0.5  0.5]
[-1. -1. -1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]
[1] validation_0-rmse:68.3176   validation_1-rmse:63.0391
[ 0.5  0.5  0.5 ...,  0.5  0.5  0.5]
[-1. -1. -1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]
[2] validation_0-rmse:68.3176   validation_1-rmse:63.0391
[ 0.5  0.5  0.5 ...,  0.5  0.5  0.5]
[-1. -1. -1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]
[3] validation_0-rmse:68.3176   validation_1-rmse:63.0391
[ 0.5  0.5  0.5 ...,  0.5  0.5  0.5]
[-1. -1. -1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]
[4] validation_0-rmse:68.3176   validation_1-rmse:63.0391
```

And for huber_approx_obj

```
[ 60.79294968  71.14537811  68.94273376 ...,  70.04405212  70.04405212 68.72246552]
[-1.99890065 -1.99919903 -1.9991467  ..., -1.9991734  -1.999173 -1.9991411]
[0] validation_0-rmse:1138.79   validation_1-rmse:1106.67

[ 60.79294968  71.14537811  68.94273376 ..., 70.04405212  70.04405212 68.72246552]
[ 1.99999702  1.99999702  1.99999702 ...,  1.99999702  1.9999970 1.99999702]
[1] validation_0-rmse:149.637   validation_1-rmse:261.029

[60.79294968  71.14537811  68.94273376 ...,  70.04405212  70.04405212 68.72246552]
[-1.9996798  -1.9997319  -1.99972188 ..., -1.99972689 -1.99972689 -1.99972081]
[2] validation_0-rmse:149.637   validation_1-rmse:261.029

[ 60.79294968  71.14537811  68.94273376 ...,  70.04405212  70.04405212 68.72246552]
[-1.9996798  -1.9997319  -1.99972188 ..., -1.99972689 -1.99972689 -1.99972081]
[3] validation_0-rmse:149.637   validation_1-rmse:261.029

[60.79294968  71.14537811  68.94273376 ...,  70.04405212  70.04405212 68.72246552]
[-1.9996798 -1.9997319 -1.99972188 ..., -1.99972689 -1.99972689 -1.999720]
[4] validation_0-rmse:149.637   validation_1-rmse:261.029
```

PS: There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840960/implement-xgboost-custom-objective-function) but with no answer. It has been a while so asking again to see if there is something that I am missing.

Comment: Why not reply with a comment on the linked question since the OP asked if anyone else had a similar problem?

Comment: Sure, will do that. Actually I think I understand the issue better now. Once I am sure of it, I will probably post my understanding as a comment there and close this question.

Comment: @mathamateur what is the default loss function for sklearns xgboost ? interesting that you have huber there, is this because that loss function is less sensitive to outliers?

Comment: @Maths12 You are right. Speaking loosely, we are interested in L1 distance between pred and true values of a group of samples rather than L2 values.
To explain in detail: Each sample, for which we know the yield rate(the target var), belongs to a group. The main problem is to predict the yield rate for a group which is the average of yield rates of the samples in the group. So what matters is the L1-distance b'n true and pred yield rates of the samples in the group. Hence we need to make sure outliers are not punished harshly which mse does.

Comment: @mathamateur, I have exactly the same issue at the moment, could you post your findings?

Comment: Same problem here, I can't find a solution that works. I have tried the implemented objective 'reg:pseudohubererror' with no luck. It just wont converge to the solution and just stops after predefined number of n_estimators. I have gone to solution to use Gradient Boosting Regressor from scikit learn instead of xgboost that has hubert implemented. Worked fine